# Is it feasible to denoise time irrelevant sensor reading with Kalman Filter and how to code it?

Tags: r, kalman-filter

After I did some research, I can understand how to implement it with time relevant functions. However, I'm not very sure about whether can I apply it to time irrelevant scenarios.

Giving that we have a simple function `y=a*x^2`, where both `y` and `x` are measured at a constant interval (say 1 min/sample) and `a` is a constant. However, both `y` and `x` measurements have white noise.

More specifically, `x` and `y` are two independently measured variables. For example, `x` is air flow rate in a duct  and the `y` is the pressure drop across the duct. Because the air flow is varying due to the variation of the fan speed, the pressure drop across the duct is also varying. The relation between the pressure drop `y` and flow rate `x` is `y=a*x^2`, however both measurement embedded white noise. Is that possible to use `Kalman Filter` to estimate a more accurate `y`? Both `x` and `y` are recorded in a constant time interval.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it feasible to implement `Kalman Filter` for the `y` reading noise reduction? Or in another word, have a better estimation of `y`?
2. If this is feasible, how to code it in R or C?

P.S.

I tried to apply `Kalman Filter` to single variable and it works well. The result is as below. I'll have a try Ben's suggestion then and have a look whether can I make it works.

[image]

Comment: By "time irrelevant" do you mean the true values of x and y are fixed?  Or are they time-varying?  If they are time-varying, do you have a differential equation for x or y?

Comment: The time irrelevant means y and x is not a function of time t. A very common example of the application of Kalman filter is to estimate the location of a moving object. Like If a car is moving at a constant speed. The distance (y) it traveled is a function of t which can be expressed as y=v*t.

Comment: Hmmm...  I'm missing something.  You're saying that x and y are time irrelevant - but in your edited question you give an example of a time-varying air-flow rate and pressure drop.  So they are time-varying and therefore time-relevant yes?

Comment: That's correct, they are time varying. The time irrelevant here only means both variables are not a function of time.

Comment: The Kalman filter is the recursive form of a minimum squared error estimator for linear time-invariant (LTI) systems.  It's not well-suited for this problem in its traditional form because the measurement (x) is a function of the square-root of the state we're estimating (y).  If instead we were measuring x and y and forming an estimate of an uncertain system parameter (i.e. if 'a' is only approximately known) then a Kalman filter would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Keith. I'll have a try your suggestion and have a look whether can I make it work.

Comment: I tried to apply Kalman Filter to both x and y separately and it works appropriately. I'll have a try Ben's suggestion and  have a look whether can I make it works when I got some times.@Ben

Answer (score 1):

I think you can apply some Kalman Filter like ideas here.

Make your state `a`, with variance `P_a`.  Your update is just `F=[1]`, and your measurement is just `H=[1]` with observation `y/x^2`.  In other words, you measure `x` and `y` and estimate `a` by solving for `a` in your original equation.  Update your scalar KF as usual.  Approximating `R` will be important.  If `x` and `y` both have zero mean Gaussian noise, then `y/x^2` certainly doesn't, but you can come up with an approximation.

Now that you have a running estimate of `a` (which is a *random constant*, so `Q=0` ideally, but maybe `Q=[tiny]` to avoid numerical issues) you can use it to get a better `y`.

You have `y_meas` and `y_est=a*x_meas^2`.  Combine those using your variances as `(R_y * a * x^2 + (P_a + R_x2) * y_meas) / (R_y + P_a + R_x2)`.  Over time as `P_a` goes to zero (you become certain of your estimate of `a`) you can see you end up combining information from your `x` and `y` measurements proportional to your trust in them individually.  Early on, when `P_a` is high you are mostly trusting the direct measurement of `y_meas` because you don't know the relationship.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution Ben. I'll have a try your suggestion when I got some spare time. I'll let you know if I make it works.